# Django, setting roles of users' models in admin

Tags: python, django

I really didn't want to ask this question, but amount of information in different tutorials and docs about this are overwhelming to me.

I have three types of users: `Admin`, `Guide`, `User`:

1. `Admin` can do anything in admin page.
2. `Admin` can change simple `Users` to `Guides`
3. `Guide` can only create `GuideTour` model objects and manage only his own tours.
4. `User` can't login to admin page.

How I can set these users in my model definition, in order to gain that kind of roles in my admin page?

Is it **single-table-inheritance** mode?

Comment: I suggest creating your own admin page rather than using Django's default. When you create your own admin page, you've more power to customize, and in my humble opinion, it is much easier to work with than modifying the admin page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using default Django's auth system (`django.contrib.auth`), you can create user groups and set most of these permissions in the admin interface (*Home › Authentication and Authorization › Groups*):

[image]

The "manage only his own tours" thing is slightly more complicated – you may want to have a `ForeignKey` field in your `Tour` model, and link the user with the object creation (and check if `request.user` is the "right" user on each edit attempt)…

Or define a method with the needed logic. See this: [Object Ownership in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999078/object-ownership-in-django)

Comment: I don't think it is worth it. In a custom Admin page, you can use decorators to give access to methods, and use basic if statements in the template to render content only if user has relevant permissions. There is so much flexibility, compared to the headache of modifying the default admin page.

Comment: @almostabeginner: Yeah, you're right. Depends on how much modification he wants to do – the custom admin might be easier after all.